# How to use Android Studio with WSL (bash) as your shell Terminal?

Tags: android, bash, shell, android-studio, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is it possible to use Android Studio and configure Windows Subsystem for Linux as a Terminal? I really don't like to work with Windows `cmd.exe`, but when I try to switch to `bash.exe`, which seems to work, it cannot build the project because there are missing e.g. `Android/sdk/build-tools/27.0.3/aidl'`.

This file is there, but it is with `.exe` suffix as it was downloaded for Windows. Any workaround to use *unix like bash for Terminal in Android Studio while being on Windows 10?

Comment: Any updates on getting Android Studio for Windows working with a WSL terminal? I'm also running into issues with building, but it's due to WSL pre-pending the current directory to the SDK path, so it cannot even find the SDK

Comment: @bitscuit have you tried putting the SDK into the path it expects to see if that works? ...and/or set a symbolic link to the SDK's real path that makes the expected path work?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it is possible. I'm doing it right now. I have an Ubuntu app as WSL and figured out that it's accessible at `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe`

So, open Android Studio and navigate to File -> Settings -> Tools -> Terminal. There fill `Shell paht` with `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe` and voilà!

Now, when you open a new terminal it will use the WSL you have installed in your machine.

I'm using Android Studio 4.0.1.

Comment: So simple and so useful. For me at least this is a game changer, thanks!

Comment: In my case, using Debian over w10, pretty much the same; but the dir was C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\TheDebianProject.DebianGNULinux_1.3.0.0_x64__76v4gfsz19hv4\debian.exe

Answer (score 1):

I'm setting this up right now and hit your question from Google looking for advice. So with that caveat, let me explain what I did to get it running and if you have follow up questions we may need to experiment together to find the answers.

First, I installed VcXserv: https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/.  This X Server for windows allows you to run graphical linux applications in WSL. You'll just need to export the display variable in your ~/.bashrc since that isn't done normally in WSL:

```
$ echo "export DISPLAY=:0" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Then you have to run XLaunch from the start menu. It takes you through the config dialogs (just choose the defaults) and it puts an icon in the notification area you can check to make sure it's running.

Then, you want to download the [**Linux** version of Android Studio 3.1](https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads). Extract it into the WSL filesystem somewhere (I used ~/apps). Then from your bash shell you can run `android-studio/bin/studio.sh` and the window will appear and begin the unboxing dialogs.

This is as far as I've gotten, right now it's downloading the SDK. I still am not sure how adb over usb is going to work or tested the emulator. I'll update this if I learn more.

---

**Update** unfortunately, VcXserv is crashing when the main Android Studio window launches. I'm going to file a bug report on it and try some other X servers if I have time later.

Comment: How's it going on this? I'm very interested in the same.

Comment: I've tried a few other windows X servers but haven't found anything better than VcXsrv. It works ok for linux Visual Studio Code and GitKraken, so I think any Electron based app should be fine, but still crashes on Android Studio. I've moved on for now.

Comment: For anyone (like me) looking at this to get Flutter working, _you don't need_ to run Android Studio. This should be sufficient. I haven't tested it yet, but I'm about to, and I'll report back when I do.

Comment: Is still someone who looking for help with it? If yes what I did is I go to: File >Settings then type in search Terminal and in shell path I added path to wsl.exe which in my case was C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe I hope that help.

Comment: Any news on this topic? I spend a few days to investigate but I never got XFCE4 running in a stable way